# changing exception cause message before throwing?

Tags: java, exception

I have a requirement to catch RunTimeException.

```
catch (RuntimeException ex) {

//here i can get message using ex.getMessage();
}
```

Here i can get exception message using **ex.getMessage()**. But i dont want this message to be returned to clients.I have to change this message and return.
But there is no setter method to change the message. **Is it possible to change the message of run time exception?**

Thanks!

Comment: Q: Is it possible to change the message of ... an exception?  A: Yes, of course: 1) catch the original exception, 2) create and throw a new, different exception of your choosing.

Comment: Create custom exception with Message that has a nice meaning and return them to client

Comment: can't i change the message of ex and return the same instead of throwing new run time exception? because if i throw new run time exception then i loose stack trace. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , It is possible. Throw a new  `RuntimeException`  passing your custom message.

Use the constructor  [`public RuntimeException(String message, Throwable cause)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html#RuntimeException%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29)

> Constructs a new runtime exception with the specified detail message and cause.

```
catch (RuntimeException ex) {

        throw new RuntimeException("Custome message", ex);

    }
```

Comment: Suresh, can't i change the message of ex and return the same instead of throwing new run time exception? Thanks!

Comment: No you can't set a message.

Comment: @user755806 Yes, true. For that I updated my post. Now you won't loos your stacktrace.

Answer (score 3):

You can create you own Custom Exception and when runtime exception catch you can throw your custom exception with proper message.

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
catch (RuntimeException ex)
{
    //here i can get message using ex.getMessage();
    throw new RuntimeException("bla bla");
}
```

If you want to keep info about original location of the first exception use this:

```
catch (RuntimeException ex)
{
    //here i can get message using ex.getMessage();
    throw new RuntimeException("bla bla", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
catch (RuntimeException ex)
{
    //here i can get message using ex.getMessage();
    throw new RuntimeException("Your message here.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (RuntimeException ex) {

     throw new SomeNewException(<Your message>);
}
```

or

```
catch (RuntimeException ex) {

     throw new RuntimeException(<Your message>);
}
```

---

```
public class SomeNewException extends Exception {
    public SomeNewException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
…..
…..
…..
}
```

---

---

Comment: can't i change the message of ex and return the same instead of throwing new run time exception? because if i throw new run time exception then i loose stack trace. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
catch (RuntimeException ex) {    
        throw new RuntimeException("your message here");
}
```